# REST api route for "delete own account"

Tags: rest

I want to design the api routes for users. Basic routes would be

- GET /users => get all users
- GET /users/:userId => get one user by userId
- POST /users => create a user
- PUT /users/:userId => replace the user with a new user object
- PATCH /users/:userId => update some user properties
- DELETE /users => delete all users
- DELETE /users/:userId => delete one user by userId

The route `POST /users` represents the **SignUp** feature. What about the **Delete my account**  feature? Would this be `DELETE /users/:userId` and I have to check which user I want to delete and only pass if the sessionUserId equals the url parameter id?

I am asking this because maybe there is a REST design for actions routes related to "myself". But I think this would be bad design anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense to me that 'delete my account' is represented by the same url and method as 'delete any other account'.

If there is a restriction to who can delete which account (including their own), then yes, you would need to know who is performing the action and prevent the action from completing if they don't have permission.